# Problem with setCursor() after closing modal JComponent

Tags: swing, java-8, modal-dialog, ubuntu-16.04, jcomponent

When I create a modal JComponent, the mouse (correctly) changes to the default cursor. However, I'm running into a weird issue when I close the component.

- If I close the component while my cursor is contained in the bounds
  of the component, the cursor will correctly revert.
- If I close the component while my cursor is outside the bounds (with esc, for example) the cursor will not revert, even with calls to setCursor().

How can I correctly have my cursor revert in both cases in a non-hacky way?

Example code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class ModalTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        // Create a frame.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Add a button.
        JButton button = new JButton();
        frame.add(button);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);

        // While the mouse is inside the JFrame, the cursor should be Cursor.HAND_CURSOR.
        // And when the modal JOptionPane is visible, the cursor should be Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR.
        // However, when that modal JComponent is closed while the cursor is outside it, it does
        // not revert to Cursor.HAND_CURSOR.
        button.setAction(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (
                    frame,
                    "Move the cursor inside, then outside of this component and press Esc. The cursor will stay default.",
                    "Cursor Test",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION
                );
                // Even if you change the cursor after, it stays default.
                frame.setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Best way to use setCursor is in a MouseListener in MouseEntered and MouseExited.

Comment: [`setCursor(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setCursor-java.awt.Cursor-): “This cursor image is displayed **when the contains method for this component returns true for the current cursor location**, and this Component is visible, displayable, and enabled.” Reads like the image is not supposed to change when the cursor is outside the bounds.

Comment: What version of Java? The cursor reverts to crosshairs for me when I press escape. (Not hand, because by then your other setting has taken effect).

Comment: Java 8 (I work with Aaron)

Comment: Java 1.8. Maybe I should clarify: the cursor should go inside the dialog then outside the dialog and inside the frame when you press escape. Is it correctly updating for you in those conditions?

Comment: Yes. I commented out the last line about crosshairs. When I run it, I have a hand cursor. I click, the modal pops up. The cursor changes to an arrow (default). I move the cursor onto it, then off of it (either back onto the JFrame, or even onto my desktop. I press Esc. The modal closes. The cursor changes back to a hand. (If I had moved the cursor all the way off of the JFrame, onto my desktop, I have to move it back over the JFrame to see the hand.) I'm using JDK 1.8.0_181 on Windows 10.

Comment: @DavidConrad You are correct. This appears to not be an issue for Windows 10. I am encountering it on Ubuntu 16.04, however.

Comment: Looks like this is the exact same thing as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32929557/incorrect-cursor-when-outside-of-modal-jdialog